# Read mid file as binary for further analyzing

Tags: c, file, filereader, readfile

So i'm trying to make a program for reading mid files and output the nodes and the delay between the nodes in a txt file for further use. however, I ran into some problems. Whenever i try to read the mid file, it just gives me random characters. however i couldn't find any solution on the problem. Even reading the file with the binary tag didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (){
    FILE *midi = fopen("myfile.mid","rb"); 
    FILE *txt = fopen("myfile.txt", "w"); 
    char line[40];

    if (midi==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        fclose(midi);
        fclose(txt);
        return 1;
    }

    while(!feof(midi)) 
    {
        fgets(line, 40, midi);
        printf("%s\n",line);
        fputs(line, txt);
        Sleep(300);
    }

    fclose(midi);
    fclose(txt);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: So i tried to use fread and fwrite instead,  but it still gives med "random" symbols. I just replaced the while loop with this code:

```
fread(line, 1, 40, midi); 
fwrite(line, 1, 40, txt);
```

Comment: You shouldn't read binary data with `fgets`...

Answer (score 3):

It's not because of "how Windows reads files", it's because a MIDI file is not human readable. It's not a text file but a binary format made to be efficient for machines to read. Treating it as a string and printing it to the screen is not going to output anything meaningful.

If you want to handle MIDI data in your program the easiest way is to find a MIDI parsing library online. The file format is not terrible complicated though, so if you're feeling inclined, you can parse it by hand too (it's a good learning exercise for binary parsing). The only C function you need is `fread` to read it into a `char` buffer - the rest is just loops and math.

Comment: Ohh, my fault. thanks. 

I do undestand binary and midi isn't hard to read, like you said, i just don't know how to make c read it in either hex or binary. by that i mean a binary or hex input

Comment: As I said, `fread` is good for binary data. Remember to use the `rb` flag on weird platforms like Windows like you have already done. And remember that printing the data to the screen directly doesn't produce anything useful.

Comment: Still couldn't get any binary input, i'm really confused about this. Shouldn't i just use fread and fwrite to the other document?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary input" if it's not what fread gets you?

Comment: It still gives me random characters when ever I try to run the code. Could it  have something to the with compiler I use? Because I really don't see why it doesn't output binary code .

Comment: @Gensarguy: If you're expecting it to output ones and zeros to the screen that's not how it works. Each `char` is 8 bits of binary data and I have told you about twice already that there's no point in printing that to the screen directly. So stop doing it!